# Replace knockout value before posting to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I'm totally new to knockout, so please bear with me :)

Long story short: Danish (european) decimals is like 1.000,99 (so dots and commas is reversed) and I'm having big problems posting the values to my MVC server.

I need to reverse the fields with danish decimal to english decimal before posting.

Here's a sample code...

```
var Item = {
    name: ko.observable(),
    price: ko.observable()
};

function SaveItem() {

    var data = {
        'item': ko.toJS(Item)
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'my_url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (d) {
        },
        error: function (err) {
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
};
```

With the code above, how can I reverse comma and dot before posting to the server?

I've tried this, but this fails...

```
function SaveItem() {

    var koData = ko.toJS(Item);
    koData.price = koData.price.replace(".", "¤").replace(",", ".").replace("¤", ".");

    var data = {
        'item': koData
    };
...
...
```

What is the best "generic" solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. You just forgot to assign the converted value to back to the property...

```
koData.price = koData.price.replace(".", "¤").replace(",", ".").replace("¤", ".");
```

Comment: Thanks :) ... let's say I have 20 "Price" variables, is there a more generic way to do it or do I have to do it one at a time?